# Thunderbird SSL error with letsencrypt cert on dovecot / postfix

Tags: email, thunderbird, ssl, certificate

I am new to Linux and I have been banging away at this problem for 12 hours and admit defeat.

I have iredmail (postfix / dovecot / roundcube webmail) installed and everything seems to work.

-Web mail works for inbound and outbound.

-Port 25 143 443 and 587 are forwarded through my firewall to the mail server

-The server host name is mail.mydomain.com

-I have a letsencrypt cert installed and it works in Nginx (no errors on webmail page) and correct cert visible

-I have added the cert to Postfix and Dovecot by using the symlink method described here: https://docs.iredmail.org/letsencrypt.html

-The cert is issued to mail.mydomain.com

However when I try to set up a Thunderbird email client (user=myname@mydomain.com) I get an error (see attached) about adding a security exception for location "domain.com" Even though the cert is correctly issued to MAIL.domain.com.  The attached shows a screen shot of the error with the certificate in question in the background.

The second attachment shows the setting I am using on the client.

This is the command I used to get the cert: `sudo certbot certonly --webroot --agree-tos --email support@anotherdomain.co.nz -d mail.mydomain.nz -w /var/www/html/`

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this would be appreciated as I am stumped.

[image: error]

[image: account setup]

Comment: No error image David :-)

Comment: I can only speculate since anything reproducible is missing here: You probably have not setup the certificates properly and chain certificates are missing. Browsers will usually successful work around such errors so it seems to work, but other application will not work around this.

Comment: I have symlinks pointing to /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem and 
/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.com/privkey.pem.  what others would i need?

Comment: error image added

Comment: What's hidden in the Location field of the Thunderbird security exception dialogue, should be the in the Subject Alt Name field of the certificate. Is that the case?

Comment: @gareththered - no, that's the problem.  The exception error has mydomain.nz while the cert has mail.mydomain.nz

Comment: How odd.  The server which Thunderbird connects to is `mail.mydomain.nz` so that's what it should be checking against.  Try adding `mydomain.nz` to your cert.

Comment: I think it is a bug in Thunderbird - an older version of Thunderbird does not give this error.  I have reported it to Bugzilla.